# Como puedo hacer para que el carrousel quede por encima del mapa?

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap-4

Quiero que un carrousel quede apenas por encima del mapa cubriendo una pequeña parte de este como se muestra en la imagen que dejo creo que debo usar position relative para que se acomode pero no estoy seguro probe de varias maneras y no funciono...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dejo el codigo tmb:

```css
#carrousel {
  position: relative;
  top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div id="carrousel">
  <div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40?text=Tab+Vestuario" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40?text=Tab+Vestuario" class="d-block w-100 " alt="...">
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x40?text=Tab+Vestuario" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<section class="mapa-home ocultar_r sombra1">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div id="google-maps">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d1675.4663239240688!2d-60.7039628!3d-32.8735014!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x0%3A0x13e34276c2723706!2sClub+Lasalle!5e0!3m2!1ses!2sar!4v1519231440585" width="100%" height="700" frameborder="0"
          style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: y con un `z-index` ya probaste?

Comment: No no, como se utiliza z-index?

Comment: puedes ponerle una clase al contenedor principal del **carrusel**, ejemplo como lo veo en el código sería algo así: `#carrousel { z-index: 1 }`

Comment: Sí gracias me sirvio!

Comment: aunque te recomendaría ponerle una **clase** al **contenedor** y usar la propieda con la **clase**

Comment: position: relative; lo que significa que su posición es relativa a X. Si pones que es posición absoluta le puedes indicar donde tiene que estar en la pantalla y si se añade despues en el DOM, pues no necesitaras ni gestionar el z-index.